# Where does Chrome store data for extensions in Development Mode?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am developing a Chrome extension, which writes and fetches data from `chrome.storage.local`
I load it into Chrome in "Developer Mode"

When I look in `/Users/raphisama/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`, I don't see the extension hash for the extension I am developing.

How do I clear the data that the extension has stored? Where is this data kept?

So far I've managed to do this only with removing and reloading the extension, but I'd prefer a simpler way

Comment: You can see the extension id on `chrome://extensions` page when its "developer mode" switch is enabled. The data will be stored in a subdirectory inside the profile e.g. `Local Extension Settings`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear \`chrome.storage.local\` cache when developing a Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812937/how-to-clear-chrome-storage-local-cache-when-developing-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: @wOxxOm not completely, since that requires adding code into the extension. Would be great if there was some way from outside the extension. Regarding the extension ID, it seems Chrome doesn't add that extension to the typical directory where extensions are kept

Comment: 1) You can run that code in devtools manually without adding code to the extension. 2) it should be stored there assuming it's chrome.storage.local otherwise it'd be in `Sync Extension Settings` but anyway you can run a recursive search on the entire profile, look for tutorials if needed.