# Remove LocalStorage item in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I tried to remove an item in the Chrome's local storage.

```js
async function removeLocalData(key: string): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(resolve => { chrome.storage.local.removeItem(key, resolve) })
}
```

Also, I found no listener parameters in API documentations, I tried this, too.

```js
chrome.storage.local.removeItem(key)
```

Both of them gave the following error.

```
Property 'removeItem' does not exist on type 'LocalStorageArea'.ts(2339)
```

I also tried `getItem()`, and it caused the same kind of error.

How to properly fix this without type casting?

Comment: `localStorage.removeItem` not working? No `Promise` needed.

Comment: I needed `chrome.storage.local`, not `window.localStorage`.
And Promise is for async to use elsewhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42561409, it will help.

Comment: Thank you! I also found that those two storage are different.

Comment: The documentation is probably convoluted but it [lists the `remove` method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#method-StorageArea-remove) and its callback.