# How can I clear storage.sync for my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I have a small chrome extension I've built using chrome.storage.sync api to cache user-entered data. However, when the user runs a delete operation, the data persists in the storage area, even after I run sync.remove and sync.clear- is there something I'm missing?

```
                chrome.storage.sync.get('tasks', function(obj) {
                
                //assign tasks array to variable
                var tasks = obj.hasOwnProperty('tasks') ? obj.tasks : [];
                    chrome.storage.sync.remove('tasks': liValue);
                    chrome.storage.sync.clear();
                //find and remove deleted task from array, checking against cached li text value
                //liValue is cached textnode value prior to dom deletion
                for(var j = 0; j < tasks.length; j++) {
                    if(tasks[j] == liValue) {
                        tasks.splice(j, 1);
                        alert("splicing " + tasks[j] + "!!!");
                    }
                }
                //reset tasks in storage
                chrome.storage.sync.set({'tasks': tasks}, function() {
                    if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
                        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
                    else
                        console.log("Tasks saved successfully");
                });

            });
```

I've looked thru the docs [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/) and as best I can tell I'm using the method signatures correctly. Somebody described a similar issue in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812937/how-to-clear-chrome-storage-local-and-chrome-storage-sync/31813035#31813035) but applying the same code does not seem to be resolving my issue.

Comment: The answer you've linked is the correct and only way to clear chrome.storage, but since it's asynchronous your code is incorrect as it doesn't wait for the call to complete. You should put the part that you want to run after clearing into the callback of clear().

Comment: [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812937/how-to-clear-chrome-storage-local-and-chrome-storage-sync/31813035#31813035)
hope this can answer your question

Comment: ok yes, that does seem to be working when I add a callback to clear() and check the storage value there, thank you. Would sync.remove operate the same way? What I'd really like to do is remove a single value from 'tasks'- I was having trouble though and resorted to .clear() as a more heavy-handed way to try to clear the cache @wOxxOm

Comment: Yes, all `chrome` methods that can have a callback per the documentation are asynchronous.

Comment: Not an answer, but I use https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill to have a Promise. Maybe it will help